# Python missing 1 requiered positional argument

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y estoy intentando que este script funcione. Esto es una idea inicial que luego me gustaría ir ampliando para practicar pero no consigo que la primera parte funcione.
Estoy intentando simplemente realizar una lista de estudiantes a la que vayas introduciendo nuevos alumnos y que luego sea posible añadirle otras opciones más adelante. ¿Alguien podría decirme qué se me está escapando? Muchas gracias.

```
class Estudiante(object):
    def __init__(self, nombre, ID):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ID = ID
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.nombre, self.ID)


class BaseDeDatos(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista_de_alumnos = [] 
    
    def __str__(self):
        rep = ", ".join(self.lista_de_alumnos)
        return rep
    
    def nuevo_alumno(self, nombre, ID):
        self.lista_de_alumnos.append(Estudiante(nombre, ID))

basededatos = BaseDeDatos()

        
Es001 = Estudiante("Marcos Lequerica", "1")
basededatos.nuevo_alumno(Estudiante)

print (BaseDeDatos.lista_de_alumnos)
```

La idea era una vez conseguido añadir al primer alumno adaptar el codigo para que sea posible añadir más desde la terminal, pero el error que me salta ahora con este de prueba es:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "untitled0.py", line 31, in 
basededatos.nuevo_alumno(Estudiante)

TypeError: nuevo_alumno() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ID'

Comment: `nuevo_alumno()` requiere dos parámetros y solo le pasas uno

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido Marcos c: Esto no tiene que ver con tu problema, pero te traerá problemas más adelante. Tu método ` __repr__` tiene un problema de logica. Devuelve una tupla, pero debería de devolver una cadena. `__repr__` es lo que es llamado cuando haces `repr(objeto)`, que devuelve la representación del objeto. Mas info aqui: https://jarroba.com/repr-y-str-de-python/ y aquí: https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-repr-and-str-in-python-65dd41538943

Comment: Ya veo el error, no obstante no veo cómo solucionarlo:

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas. Pero la verdad es que no me estoy aclarando nada con cómo puedo arreglarlo.¿ Alguien podría hacerme el favor de explicarme cómo lo arreglaría para que tenga un ejemplo de cómo puede hacerse? Muchas gracias.